# Ajax Request in laravel 4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I'm newbie in laravel. I'm using version 4 and i'm trying to do ajax request in my login form. Since my login form is in bootstrap modal, before the form submit it will check if the input password and username are equal to password and username in my database using ajax. Then if the form submit it will reload only the page.
here is my code:

**js-script.php**

```
 $("#login-submit").submit(function(event) {
  var un = 'input[name="username"]';
  var pw = 'input[name="password-login"]';

   $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                url: "/login=success",
                data : { 'un' : $(un).val(), 'pw' : $(pw).val() },  
                datatype: "json", 
                success: function(data){  
                    if(data == 0){
                        $('#message-error').show();
                        setTimeout(function() {
                             $('#message-error').hide();
                        }, 5000);
                    }
                    if(data != 0){
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                }
            });

});
```

**usercontroller.php**

```
// Login User
    public function login(){
        $un = Input::get( 'un' );
        $pw = Input::get( 'pw' );   
        $password = md5($pw);
        if (Auth::attempt(array('username'=>$un, 'password'=>$password))) {
            return Redirect::to('/login=success')->with('message', 'You are now logged in!');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('users/login')
                ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
                ->withInput();
        }     

    }
```

**route.php**

```
Route::post('/login=success', 'UserController@login');
```

i dont know how to access my database and do some queries in my ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting to db and checking for the given inputs. You should put in your controller:

```
$num = DB::where("username", $username)->where("password", $password)->count();

if ($num != 0)
{
 // do something
}
```

`$password` is probably a hashed password. It depends on if you have used Laravel's Auth, then you will want to hash it using Laravel's:

```
$hashedPassword = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
```

Though you can then check it against using Laravel's Hash again:

```
if (Hash::check($_POST['password'], $hashedPassword))
{
    // The passwords match...
}
```

If your site has its DB working in Laravel, then you database configuration is set in Laravel, else you have to set your DB configuration in Laravel. For that you may consult with Laravel's documentation.

All of the above information are also available through Laravel's documentation. For hashing you can visit:

http://laravel.com/docs/security

Comment: i'm getting an error 404 not found in my developer tools console.The requested url not found on my server. Can you guide me how  can i reload the same page but in my addressbar should be like this public/login=success

Comment: Let me ask you this question: your ajax call is responding 404? If so I should give you a workaround...

Comment: i think that error looks for a page in my directory that assigned in my route.php but i searched for tutorials on how you can do ajax in laravel and this codes are likely same as them.

Comment: Please answer to my question: is your ajax responding 404? We have to debug your application step-by-step.

Comment: then you have to configure your AJAX's URL based on the LARAVEL's function...before giving you an answer you have to send your ajax request to a full URL of the same domain. For instance, something like this (if you are working on localhost) : `http://localhost/public/login/success` and then give us the result to investigate the problem more...